# Why don't all of the tests in WWW::Selenium appear to run?

Tags: perl, selenium-rc

I have a test file that includes the following code. The page opens up and the first three tests run but the next 3 don't run. They don't fail. They just don't run.

```
my $sel = Test::WWW::Selenium->new(
    host         => 'localhost',
    port         => 4444,
    browser      => 'firefox',
    browser_url  => $uri,
    singlewindow => 1,
);

$sel->open_ok('/');
$sel->is_element_present_ok('username');
$sel->is_element_present_ok('password');
$sel->is_text_present('Username');
$sel->is_text_present('Password');
$sel->is_text_present('Login');
```

Then I log into the form.

```
$sel->type("name=username", $username);
$sel->type("name=password", $password);
$sel->submit('dom=document.forms["formfield"]');
$sel->is_text_present('Change Log');
```

I'm able to log in and the text 'Change Log' is present on the page but the test never runs. The test for text that doesn't exist doesn't run either.

```
$sel->is_text_present('Fee based gumbo');
```

Anyone know why these tests wouldn't be running?

I also have a test for a link

```
<a style="text-decoration:none;" href="/settings">Settings</a>
```

as

```
$sel->click('//a[contains(@href, "/settings")]');
```

That causes the test to crash. Is there a reason why that wouldn't be found?

*EDIT:*

I'd been using the [WWW::Selenium](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aSelenium) page, not [Test::WWW::Selenium](http://p3rl.org/Test%3a%3aWWW%3a%3aSelenium).

This module is a WWW::Selenium subclass providing some methods useful for writing tests. For each Selenium command (`open`, `click`, `type`, …) there is a corresponding `<command>_ok` method that checks the return value (`open_ok`, `click_ok`, `type_ok`).

The xpath problem `$sel->click('//a[contains(@href, "/settings")]');` simply just needed the double quotes removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd been using the WWW::Selenium page not the Test::WWW::Selenium at http://search.cpan.org/~lukec/Test-WWW-Selenium-1.32/lib/Test/WWW/Selenium.pm

This module is a WWW::Selenium subclass providing some methods useful for writing tests. For each Selenium command (open, click, type, ...) there is a corresponding _ok method that checks the return value (open_ok, click_ok, type_ok).

The xpath problem $sel->click('//a[contains(@href, "/settings")]');

simply just needed the double quotes removed.